# Count maximum length of value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is small sample of my `salesDetail` table and its `[Kind of business]` column:

```
kind of business
-------------------------------------
Retail and food services sales, total â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦...â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦

Total (excl. motor vehicle and parts dealers) â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦...â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦
```

I want to separate all data by white space and then calculate  maximum length of separated string.
I tried this code

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(value))
FROM salesDetail
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([kind of business], ' ')
GROUP BY value
```

This returns the length of individual string not maximum of all string.

The results are shown in the screenshot below.

So then I tried this code:

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT(value))
FROM salesDetail
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([kind of business], ' ')
GROUP BY value
```

This one throws an error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Expected output:

```
147    (this is maximum number in this column)
```

I want maximum value from the result as shown in picture

How should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please include the expected output so that we know what you want here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 
I have put expected output. I want maximum value from the result as shown in picture

Comment: @AaronBertrand exactly that's what i want to say. Sorry for my bad English. I want to calculate maximum length of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the final `GROUP BY`

```
select max(len(value)) max_len
from salesDetail 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([kind of business], ' ')
```